# no visible @interface for 'UITableView' declares the selector 'registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, compiler-errors, xcode6

I've been writing some table view stuff and have just encountered something frustrating.

I have the following code in a few places.

```
[table registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
```

This works fine, builds and runs on the simulator. When I switch to build for device I get errors at call sites.

```
error: no visible @interface for 'UITableView' declares the selector 'registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:'
```

Which is very strange as I can cmd click on the selector and I get brought to it's definition. So Xcode knows it exists.

My deployment target is iOS 6, I'm using Xcode 6, this all worked fine a few days ago. But now it's failing and it's extremely annoying.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

#### UPDATE

I've been messing around with this and have noticed that I can build without the error above when I change my configuration to Release. So the issues is something with the Debug configuration.

I then went back to debug and started to change build settings one by one to match the Release configuration.

For some reason setting the optimisation level is the setting that makes things work. Setting debug to have `Fast` instead of `None` for Debug seems to have an effect on the file compiling.

I'm starting to wonder if this is an issue with Xcode 6.0.1

Any further help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: I assume that you have tried unsuccessfully to clean and rebuild from scratch, right?

Comment: By "clean and rebuild from scratch" do you mean, clean project and derived data, and rebuild, or, create a new project file and rebuild all the settings?

Comment: I mean just cleaning the project (Command-K, if I remember it right), and hitting "build".

Comment: Ye I tried that alright.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, but if it were pervasive one would expect it to be more widely discussed.  It might be necessary to reproduce in a whole new project.

Comment: You might check for a bug in your precompiled header stuff, if you've modified it at all.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to those who gave suggestions. I finally found a solution that worked for me.

I had previously tried cleaning my derived data for the project, but with no luck. After a while of looking through my build settings and messing with build locations I decided to have a look in the derived data folder in Finder.

Once there I spotted something that was a little odd. There were multiple entries for the project I was trying to compile, about 7. I think this the result of blasting out my local git repository a few times over the past months, and Xcode not realising the project was the same as the last.

Anyway, I closed Xcode and manually deleted the entire Derived Data folder `/Users/<username>/Library/Developer/Xcode`, then reopened Xcode. Built my project and boom.... success!

Happy that's over now, and hope this helps someone else in the future.

Thanks again to anyone who helped.

Comment: Thanks this also worked for me after wasting a lot of time fiddling with build configurations. Another thing that worked was renaming the Debug configuration to something else. As soon as I renamed it back to Debug the problem would reappear.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the "Derived Data" folder is a temporary solution and the error will come back soon. My solution was to delete the .h and .m files from the project and add them again. This was a permanent solution